# Logging lock-screen events

Tags: linux, fedora, gnome, logging, lock-screen

## Problem

See the exact date & time a user locks and unlocks his work station - running Fedora 18.

## Question

Is there any way to log an event of a user entering and exiting "lock-screen" on fedora 18 (or a general linux solution)?

## Tried

1. Tried looking at `/var/log/boot` - no help. And looking at `/var/log/messages` I found the message `systemd-logind[xxx]: New session 140 of user YYY`, but could not find the lock-screen (gnome?) event.
2. Tried looking at `/var/log/audit/audit.log` which has a lot of PAM related messages about all sort of users and services, but I'm not really sure what to look for to find the lock-screen activity

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is another solution using "dbus-monitor". A little bash script logging screen activity.

```
exit_report(){
echo "$(date) Monitoring Terminated."
}
trap "exit_report; exit;" 0

lockmon() {
adddate() {
    while IFS= read -r line; do
      echo "$(date) $line" | grep "boolean" | sed 's/   boolean true/Screen Locked/' | sed 's/   boolean false/Screen Unlocked/'
    done
}
echo "$(date) Monitoring Started."
dbus-monitor --session "type='signal',interface='org.gnome.ScreenSaver'" | adddate

}

lockmon >> lock_screen.log
```

Comment: I put this in a `.sh` file and added it to Gnome's startup applications. Does what it says on the tin, thx

Comment: I had some problems after an Ubuntu upgrade, so I made [an improved version of this script](https://gist.github.com/ameenross/e2ef81485dc3237c0da08e9663d69795).

Answer (score 8):

Try to take a look at `/var/log/auth.log`. You should see some related messages from PAM and/or the screensaver application.

Comment: I have no `/var/log/auth.log`, I do have `/var/log/audit/audit.log` which has a lot of PAM related messages about all sort of users and services, but I'm not really sure what to look for to find the lock-screen activity

Comment: I have /var/log/auth.log and there's no message from PAM nor the screensaver app relative to the lock up / lock out events.

Answer (score 5):

Yes it doesn't seem to be logged anywhere for you. [@tutuDajuju has a good solution](https://superuser.com/a/668628) so I thought I'd port it to bash (and remove the dependence on using gnome, this should work regardless of desktop environment) for those that are interested.
If you have this running in the background and pipe it to a log file you will have your log.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

#prints out, among other things;
#      string "org.kde.screensaver"
#transform it to 'org.kde.screensaver'
service=$(\
    dbus-send \
        --session \
        --dest=org.freedesktop.DBus \
        --type=method_call \
        --print-reply \
        /org/freedesktop/DBus org.freedesktop.DBus.ListNames \
    | grep -o '[^"]*.screensaver'
)

#prints out, among other things;
#method bool org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver.SetActive(bool e)
#transform it to 'org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver'
interface=$(
    qdbus \
        $service /ScreenSaver \
    | grep -oP '[^ ]*(?=.SetActive)'
)

path='/ScreenSaver'

#monitor it with a while loop
dbus-monitor "type='signal',interface='$interface',member='ActiveChanged',path='$path'" \
| while read -r line; do
    #ignore the metadata and pull the 'boolean <true/false>' line
    read line

    #check if it is set to true
    if echo $line | grep -q 'true'; then
        echo "Locked at $(date)"
    else
        echo "Unlocked at $(date)"
    fi
done
```

This ran fine on my Fedora with KDE, but I guess it should work on other things like Debian with gnome et cetera.
<sub>You may have issues if your `grep` doesn't support `-P` (in which case you can just use `sed`).</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Might as well answer this although it's not my answer (my boss provided me with the solution) to help others with the same need (or curious minds).

tl;dr: Use D-Bus to get lockscreen's actived/deactived signals.

It seems [D-Bus](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/dbus/) messaging is widely supported by GNOME apps, and the [ScreenSaver app specifically](https://people.gnome.org/~mccann/gnome-screensaver/docs/gnome-screensaver.html#gs-signals), and it seems that [the gnome-screensaver app](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gnome-screensaver) is the official locking app for Gnome shell.

So, to test it out, I just ran [dbus-monitor](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dbus-monitor) and get the response:

```
dbus-monitor --session "type='signal',interface='org.gnome.ScreenSaver'"
```

I've written a little python script to log this activity into a file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from datetime import datetime
import os
import pwd
import subprocess
import time

LOG_FILE = os.path.expanduser('~/hours_log.csv')


cmd = subprocess.Popen(["dbus-monitor \"type='signal',interface="
                        "'org.gnome.ScreenSaver'\""], shell=True,
                       stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

running = 0
while 1:
    time.sleep(0.1)
    if running:
        output = cmd.stdout.readline()
        status = 'unlocked' if 'true' in output else 'locked'
        new_line = "{time} {user} {status} the screen\n".format(
            time=datetime.now().ctime(),
            user=pwd.getpwuid(os.getuid())[0],
            status=status
        )
        with open(LOG_FILE, 'a') as f:
            f.write(new_line)

        running = 0
    line = cmd.stdout.readline()
    if "ActiveChange" in line and 'org.gnome.ScreenSaver' in line:
        running = 1
```

Comment: Polling ? what a waste of resources.

Answer (score 2):

which screensaver you are using ? if it is xscreensaver, turn on the log options and try to monitor the log file.

http://www.jwz.org/xscreensaver/man1.html

Comment: I just wrote in my own answer that the default in gnome shell is gnome-screensaver, which appears to be what I'm using (since fedora installs gnome shell by default)...

Answer (score 2):

**Linux Mint 17.1.**
My dbus string looks like this:

```bsh
 dbus-monitor --session "type='signal',path='/org/cinnamon/ScreenSaver'"
```

or it may look like this

```bsh
dbus-monitor --session "type='signal',interface='org.cinnamon.ScreenSaver'"
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm using XFCE and XScreensaver. The dbus-monitor neither xscreensaver logging does not work for me. So I have found another solution. I hope it will be usable for other people too.

I run this command during XFCE start:

```
/usr/bin/xscreensaver-command -watch |logger -t lockLogger
```

Lock / unlock events are logged to the `/var/log/messages` and can be retrieved by

```
grep lockLogger /var/log/messages
```