# KDE screen lock log?

Tags: kde, screensaver

When the screen is locked in KDE (my specific version is Kubuntu but hopefully this is something that is generic Linux), is the event logged?  If so where would I look to find it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use D-Bus to get lockscreen's actived/deactived signals. The name of the screen saver service will vary from system to system. In general, KDE uses `org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver` and Gnome uses `org.gnome.ScreenSaver`. This cannot be relied upon though, for example, Mint uses `org.cinnamon.ScreenSaver`.

**Helpful Commands**

These assume that your screen saver is `org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver` and your DBus service is `org.freedesktop.DBus`. You may need to adjust this for other systems. Use the following information to find out what your system uses:

- To get a [list of the dbus services](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/46309/46040) available in your current session, use:

  ```
  dbus-send --session --dest=org.freedesktop.DBus --type=method_call --print-reply /org/freedesktop/DBus org.freedesktop.DBus.ListNames
  ```

  Add `|grep screensaver` to the end if you just want the screen saver services available.
- To get a list of the commands supported by your screen saver service, use:

  ```
  qdbus org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver /ScreenSaver
  ```
- To invoke a command, use:

  ```
  dbus-send --session --dest=org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver --type=method_call --print-reply --reply-timeout=20000 /org/freedesktop/ScreenSaver org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver.SetActive boolean:true
  ```

  Where `SetActive` was listed in the list of supported commands and takes a boolean value.
- To monitor a service:

  ```
  dbus-monitor --session "type='signal',interface='org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver'"
  ```

**Automation**

Now that you understand how your system works, you can use a python script to log this activity into a file:

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python
from datetime import datetime
import os
import pwd
import subprocess
import time

LOG_FILE = os.path.expanduser('~/hours_log.csv')


cmd = subprocess.Popen(["dbus-monitor \"type='signal',interface="
                        "'org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver'\""], shell=True,
                       stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

running = 0
while 1:
    time.sleep(0.1)
    if running:
        output = cmd.stdout.readline()
        status = 'unlocked' if 'true' in output else 'locked'
        new_line = "{time} {user} {status} the screen\n".format(
            time=datetime.now().ctime(),
            user=pwd.getpwuid(os.getuid())[0],
            status=status
        )
        with open(LOG_FILE, 'a') as f:
            f.write(new_line)

        running = 0
    line = cmd.stdout.readline()
    if "ActiveChange" in line and 'org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver' in line:
        running = 1
```

[ Source: [logging-lock-screen-events](https://superuser.com/a/668628/145045) ]

Comment: It works, but I get duplicate entries.

Answer (score 1):

It isnt logged anywhere for you, but like @krowe said, you can hook into it.
I developed this bash script which works out your setup's specifics for you, if you have this running in the background and pipe it to a log file you will have your log.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

#prints out, among other things;
#      string "org.kde.screensaver"
#transform it to 'org.kde.screensaver'
service=$(\
    dbus-send \
        --session \
        --dest=org.freedesktop.DBus \
        --type=method_call \
        --print-reply \
        /org/freedesktop/DBus org.freedesktop.DBus.ListNames \
    | grep -o '[^"]*.screensaver'
)

#prints out, among other things;
#method bool org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver.SetActive(bool e)
#transform it to 'org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver'
interface=$(
    qdbus \
        $service /ScreenSaver \
    | grep -oP '[^ ]*(?=.SetActive)'
)

path='/ScreenSaver'

#monitor it with a while loop
dbus-monitor "type='signal',interface='$interface',member='ActiveChanged',path='$path'" \
| while read -r line; do
    #ignore the metadata and pull the 'boolean <true/false>' line
    read line

    #check if it is set to true
    if echo $line | grep -q 'true'; then
        echo "Locked at $(date)"
    else
        echo "Unlocked at $(date)"
    fi
done
```

This ran fine on my Fedora with KDE, but I guess it should work on other things like Debian with gnome et cetera.
<sub>You may have issues if your `grep` doesn't support `-P` (in which case you can just use `sed`).</sub>

Comment: Works well, running as an OpenRC service on Gentoo Linux with KDE/Plasma.  However, I get double entries when the service starts and quadruple when I close my laptop.  I fixed this by redirecting the output of the `echo` lines to file in this script (`>> $LOGFILE) and adding between the last `fi` and `done` the lines `uniq $LOGFILE > $LOGFILE.temp` followed by `mv -f $LOGFILE.temp $LOGFILE`.  The fiirst saves unique entries in a temporary file, and the second replaces the original with the new file.

Comment: Unfortunately, this seems to have stopped working after a KDE/Plasma upgrade from 5.27.8 to 5.27.9(!)