# Run script on log in and as the user loggin in (not the root)

Tags: linux, boot, bash, linux-mint, systemd

I would like to run something like that on loggin in:
[Logging lock-screen events](https://superuser.com/questions/662974/logging-lock-screen-events#answer-832111)

I then tried to use both systemd and upstart described in this answer:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/228304/how-do-i-run-a-script-at-start-up#answer-228313

However my script is never launched on start up.
The script run fine if I launch it myself once logged in.

The script I placed to `/etc/init.d/` looks like :

```
#!/bin/bash
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          screenlogger
# Required-Start:    $local_fs $network
# Required-Stop:     $local_fs
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: screenlogger
# Description:       screenlogger
### END INIT INFO

export SCREENLOGGER="$HOME/.bin/screenlogger.sh"

if [ -e "$SCREENLOGGER" ]
then
  $SCREENLOGGER
fi
```

Then I realised that if I just put a `echo "$HOME" >> /home/myloggin/test` the file will allways be empty on reboot.

Also, it seems that the script is runned at boot and not on log in and the user is `root` not myself.

So I would like to know if that is possible to run a script on log in as the user process owner (with `$HOME` fullfilled) ?

Comment: `$HOME` is a variable set for each single user... it is not global. What do you really want: to run as if the user x is logged or only to run from that user *home*? It's different... Ps> welcome (out) on SuperUser

Comment: Have you tried using `su` and becoming the user you want to be executing that script?

Comment: ... another specification request:  do you want to execute the script at boot time (when computer starts) or at log-in time (when a specific user logs)?

Comment: if its desired to run at 'login' time put it in that users' .autostart folder on a *nix machine ~/.autostart/  OR ~/scripts  and have something in the $(shell)rc  calling that ~/scripts/foo.sh

Comment: (Sorry for the newlines...).  
I tried with the `~/.config/autostart` and it does not launch at log in either.
Tried mannualy to do:
`$ IFS== read var query <<< \`cat .config/autostart/screenlogger.desktop | grep Exec\``
`$query`
And works fine.

Didn't find anything about `~/.autostart/`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using [`~/.xprofile`](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/blob/master/.xprofile) for to apply user-level settings and start user-level services, for example:

```
xss-lock slock &
```

I've never had problems with X not being initialised at the point when this file is run.

Comment: Running the script before that X11 is initialised wont let me monitor `org.mate.ScreenSaver` or maybe I missed something.

Comment: I finally used your solution `sleep 5 && $HOME/.bin/screenlogger.sh &` even if I would prefere to replace the `sleep 5` with waiting for that the X11 server is initialised.